# Two Activity in different processes, When jump it appear black screen or white screen

Tags: android

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:process=":abc"
            />
```

When I use this code to jump activity, it appear black screen or white screen in short time, how to slove ??

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `android:windowDisablePreview`:

```
 <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <!-- This disables the black preview screen -->
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a style and set such attrs:

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
 <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

then apply this style to your activity.